# How to integrate facebook log in in react native

Tags: facebook, react-native, mobile

I want to integrate the social log in in react native.
I used reacct-native-fbsdk module and has set the basic settings.
So when I press the facebook button, it passed to the facebook.com
However, the error occurred like this image.
[image]

Please let me know the reason.
Thanks and best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app is still in development mode in facebook developers console. You need to make it to statse of live :

below image portrays the status of Live, and its selected. try that out

[image: facebook developer]

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Facebook developer.com changed a little and " live "  changed to " posted by ".  I already made it to " Posted by " .But still now, there is same error.

Comment: did you use firebase for facebook login, its the easisest